# I m trying to create an Image Slide View in a fragment?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, fragment

Below is my code for instantiating my `ViewPagerAdapter`. I was following an tutorial that was using an activity, as I am using a fragment, I've tried to figure out what I should change. My error is on this line

```
 **ViewPagerAdapter viewPagerAdapter = ViewPagerAdapter.setAndroidContext(this.getActivity());**
```

The error reads as Cannot resolve method `setAndroidContext()`.

```
public class HomeFragment extends Fragment {

    ViewPager viewpager;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);

        viewpager = (ViewPager) getView().findViewById(R.id.viewpager);

        **ViewPagerAdapter viewPagerAdapter = ViewPagerAdapter.setAndroidContext(this.getActivity());**
        }

    }
```

Comment: your return statement is before the adapter, make the return statement at end of the oncreateview method. Your adapter method is unreachable.

Comment: The only difference between using context in activity and fragment is that inside fragments you will need to pass context parameter as getContext() or getActvity() and in Activities you will pass the "this" object or ClassName.this as and when required

Answer (score -1, accepted):

> Try following

```
 @Override
 public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,
                       ViewGroup container,
                       Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   View view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);
   ViewPager pager=(ViewPager)view.findViewById(R.id.viewpager);

   pager.setAdapter("your adapter");

   return view;
}
```

Comment: after a bit of tweeking. this is what I have

Comment: return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);
        viewPager = (ViewPager) view.findViewById(R.id.view_pager);
        adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(this.getActivity());
        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
        return view;
    }

Comment: However error with return view; and view.FindViewbyId

Comment: In your fragment_home layout, are you define your ViewPager?